# Problem in using Django model's related_query_name

Tags: django, django-models

I have two Django projects which share the same model files.  I do all the DB migrations on project A, and use the data in project B. Everything works but one thing.
I have a User model and Post model

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="posts", related_query_name='post')
  ...
```

Using related_name `user.posts.all()` works for both projects, but not the related_query_name
`User.objects.filter(post=[whatever])` works in project A but not B.
It reports `Django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'post' into field.`
I also have a third project also using the same DB and also works. The difference is project B is not using it as the default DB, but does it matter? I just don't know why related_query_name only works for A project but B.

Comment: Thoughts: Same django version in all projects? Set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting to your custom model in all projects? Run all migrations for the relevant apps?

Comment: @user2390182 Yes, both are Django 3.2.12. All migrations are applied, and for related_name and related_query_name migration is not needed.

Comment: What about the setting? Are you sure `User` is your model and not the original as you would get with e.g. `get_user_model()` and default settings?

Comment: @user2390182 Yes, and only project B has an issue even though models are the same

Comment: Maybe the order of `INSTALLED_APPS` can play a role here? Depending on *when* your models get registered by your django app it might run into problems related to [this issue](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name)